# Maven web resource filtering SNAPSHOT version

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

Using Maven, I'd like to update a parameter in a file to either `"true"` or `"false"` based on if the version number is a SNAPSHOT or not.  Currently I use the maven-war-plugin to update some other properties based on Maven properties.  I've tried to use the maven properties along with the maven-release-plugin, but this seems to not work:

Maven pom.xml:

```
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <someProperty>value</somePropery>
        <isSnapshot>true</isSnapshot>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <properties>
                <isSnapshot>false</isSnapshot>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Running a `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform` seems to ignore the overridden property in the final war.  This seems to stem from the fact that the release profile is active during the `release:perform` phase, but not the `release:prepare` phase when the war is actually built.

Is there a better way to do this or am I missing something?

**Edit:**

I am running this release from a project pom, which this war pom is a submodule.

Comment: Check the output of the effective pom when -Prelease. Command: 'mvn -Prelease help:effective-pom'

Comment: that command shows a pom with `<isSnapshot>false</isSnapshot>`